# Prob. 6, Sec. 30, in Munkres' TOPOLOGY, 2nd ed: $\mathbb{R}_\ell$ and $I_0^2$ are not metrizable

Tags: general-topology, compactness, solution-verification, second-countable, metrizability

Here is Prob. 6, Sec. 30, in the book *Topology* by James R. Munkres, 2nd edition:

> Show that $\mathbb{R}_\ell$ and $I_0^2$ are not metrizable.

My Attempt:

> First, we consider $\mathbb{R}_\ell$. Recall that $\mathbb{R}_\ell$ is the set of real numbers with the so-called "lower limit topology" having as a basis the collection
> $$ \big\{ \, [a, b) \, \colon \, a \in \mathbb{R}, b \in \mathbb{R}, a < b \, \big\} $$
> of all the (bounded) closed-from-the-left-open-from-the-right intervals on the real line.

> Every metrizable Lindelof space has a countable basis, by Prob. 5 (b), Sec. 30, in Munkres. [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3648308/prob-5-b-sec-30-in-munkres-topology-2nd-ed-every-metrizable-lindelof-sp) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4396651/prob-5-b-sec-30-in-munkres-topology-2nd-ed-every-metrizable-lindelof-sp) is my Math SE post on this very problem.

> However, $\mathbb{R}_\ell$ is a Lindelof space that has no countable basis. Please refer to Example 3, Sec. 30, in Munkres.

> Therefore $\mathbb{R}_\ell$ is not metrizable.

Am I right?

> Now we consider $I_0^2$. Recall that $I_0^2 = [0, 1] \times [0, 1]$ with the dictionary order topology.

> The topological space $I_0^2$ is a simply ordered set that has the least upper bound property; so by Theorem 27.1 in Munkres every closed interval $[ a\times b, c \times d]$ in $I_0^2$ is compact, where $a \times b \in I_0^2$, $c \times d \in I_0^2$ and
> $$ a \times b <_{I_0^2} c \times d. $$
> In particular, we have
> $$ I_0^2 = [0 \times 0, 1 \times 1 ] $$
> so that $I_0^2$ itself is compact.

> As has been shown in Example 5, Sec. 30, in Munkres, the subspace $A \colon= [0, 1] \times (0, 1)$ of $I_0^2$ is not Lindelof.

> Since every second-countable space is Lindelof, by Theorem 30.3 (a) in Munkres, and since the subspace $A = [0, 1] \times (0, 1)$ of $I_0^2$ is not Lindelof, therefore we can conclude that $A$ is not second countable either.

> But since every subspace of a second countable space is also second-countable, by Theorem 30.2 in Munkres, and since the subspace $A = [0, 1] \times (0, 1)$ of the topological space $I_0^2$ is not second countable, therefore we can conclude that $I_0^2$ itself is not second-countable either. Thus $I_0^2$ has no countable basis.

> Thus $I_0^2$ is a compact space having no countable basis.

> But every compact metrizable space has a countable basis, by Prob. 4, Sec. 30, in Munkres; [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3647069/prob-4-sec-30-in-munkres-topology-2nd-ed-every-compact-metrizable-space-h) is my Math SE post on this very problem.

> Finally since every compact metrizable space has a countable basis and since $I_0^2$ is a compact space that has no countable basis, therefore we can conclude that $I_0^2$ is not metrizable.

Am I right?

Is each one of the two parts of my proof correct as a whole? If so, is each and every detail correct as well? Is my presentation in both parts clear enough? If not, then where are the problem areas?

Comment: Have you seen my post [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2812134/4280) where I show equivalence of Lindelöf and separable etc. for metrisable spaces.

Comment: Another way to show $I_0$ is not metrizable is to show that the closed subset $C=[0,1]\times \{0,1\}$ is not a $G_{\delta}$ set: If $U_n$ is open and $U_n\supset C$ then $U_n\supset V_n\times [0,1]$ where $V_n$ is a dense open subset of $[0,1].$ By the Baire Category Theorem , the set $W=\cap_{n\in \Bbb N}V_n$ is not empty. And $\cap_{n\in \Bbb N}U_n\supset W\times [0,1],$ so $\cap_{n\in\Bbb N}U_n\ne C.$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It’s fine, if a little long-winded.

For future reference you might want to note that a space with an uncountable pairwise disjoint family $\mathscr{U}$ of non-empty open sets cannot be second countable or separable, since each member of $\mathscr{U}$ must contain a different member of any base for the topology and a different point of any dense subset. The lexicographically ordered square has such a family, namely, $\big\{\{x\}\times(0,1):x\in[0,1]\big\}$.